# Hide a C# GUI Form

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Despite the irony of this question, how could you accomplish hiding a form, or even better running the complete application silently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set its [`WindowState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.windowstate%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to Minimized.

You can also hide it from the Taksbar by setting [`ShowInTaskbar=false;`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.showintaskbar.aspx)

With these two properties, you can fully control the display of your form, depending on your own requirements.

Answer (score 3):

Is there any reason you need to use a form?  Why not make it a console application?  If you need both scenarios, both UI and "silent," you can put the common functionality in a separate, class library project, compile it, and reference the DLL in both a winforms project and a console project.

Answer (score 3):

To run an application silently make it a window's service rather than winforms app

Answer (score 3):

If you don't your form to be shown, don't call `.Show()` on your form from `Main()`.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=973 ,here you can Hide any Window you want from C#.